# number datatype is not recognising in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have seen a query syntax in a website related to sql

and i wanted to create a table exactly as mentioned in the website

syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE product_master 
  (
  Product_id NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT promstr_col1_pid_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Product_name VARCHAR2(30),
  Product_price NUMBER(5)
  );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT promstr_col1_pid_pk PRIMARY KEY , Product_name VARCHAR2(30)' at line 1

it is not recognising number datatype;
is there any way to make it work.....

my doubt is how can they exicute this query successfully...
why iam not able to exicute it....

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.k. Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

Comment: What is "the website"? What makes you think that such a datatype exists in MySQL?

Comment: mam,i have exicuted query from this site; http://www.rebellionrider.com/sql-primary-key/

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your query that MySQL does not support:

- Inline naming of primary key constraints.
- `NUMBER`, which is an Oracle-specific data type.
- `VARCHAR2`, which is an Oracle-specific data type.

It is unclear exactly what you want.  But you can start with:

```
CREATE TABLE product_master (
  Product_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  Product_name VARCHAR(30),
  Product_price int
);
```

I don't recommend representing "prices" as integers.  Normally, this would be a `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` datatype (these are SQL Standard types).  However, `int` is consistent with your original table.

Comment: or should use oracle instead of mysql...